# Regex match string but exclude instances of a substring

Tags: regex, string, substring

For instance..

Sample Text: `<tag>AandBandCandD</tag>`

I need to match everything that occurs between `tag>` and `</tag` excluding any instances of "and" so the result is:

> "ABCD"

Comment: My sample text broke because of the tags. Should be "tag>AandBandCandD</tag"

Comment: fixed that up, your question should read as you intended, please check

Comment: What language are you using? Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: It's being used in an application UI. I have zero programming options. Currently using somegthing like "tag>(.*?)</tag" but don't know how to exclude the "and"s

Comment: @user1596224: Without knowing what regular expression engine is used for the application UI's we can only guess. There is no "standard" regular expression language. Every language has its own implementation and they are all different. It could be that what you are trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this in two steps:

- First extract the contents of the tag.
- Next replace all occurrences of `and` with the empty string.

Regular expressions are not the right tool for either step:

- The first step can be better achieved using an HTML parser.
- The second step doesn't need the complexity of regular expressions. A simple string replace will work.

---

**Update**

If you are forced to use a *single* regular expression, then it's probably not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately the field only takes regular expressions. Again this is an input field of a 3rd party application. I have 0 development options.

Comment: I think that may be the case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can try, anyway.

```
(?<=<tag>)(?:((?!and).)+(?:and)?)*(?=</tag>)
```

Broken down for readability:

```
(?<=
  <tag>
)
(?:
  (
    (?!
      and
    )
    .
  )+
  (?:and)?
)*
(?=
  </tag>
)
```

I'm pretty sure this would produce a number of matches equal to the text between the `and`s. But without knowing the exact regex language in question, there's a ton of things that could break this by being just a little different.